# How to make two PCs on LAN act as one?

Tags: windows, networking, lan

I have one computer connected to the internet, then second computer connected to the first. I want the second PC (which is not connected to internet) to act like the first PC. I dont have a router and my internet connection is based on a MAC address. The best solution for me would be these two computers acting on the local area network as one.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Either configure [connection sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing),  [bridge the connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-a-network-bridge) on your first PC, or purchase a router.

Comment: I would use Internet Connection Sharing (or whatever it's called these days) instead.

Comment: Dead right, edited to add that in.

Comment: Should add that almost every router in existence today can do Admin Configured MAC.

Answer (score 2):

Purchase a router. You can use Internet connection sharing, but you're asking for configuration headaches down the road. It's a lot easier in the long run to just have a router and run two network cables to the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

first, a cross-over cable between the two PCs is a best.
second, clone mac address of the first PC to the second PC 
third, clone the IP of the first PC to the second PC.
that's it.
Both PCs work as one without internet connection sharing.
hope it helps